# Difference between Task.Run(()=> DoWorkAsync()) and new Thread(async()=> DoWorkAsync());

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, threadpool

I recently came across some code which confused me heavily, I have always thought that you must use threads or Async tasks, not mix and match between them,

```
public async Task DoWork()
{
   Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Now I saw code calling this like so:

```
public void Main()
{
    var thread = new Thread(async () => { await DoWorkAync(); })
                {
                    Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest,
                    IsBackground = true
                };
        // Start thread
        proccessThread.Start();
}
```

Now this magically seemed to NOT create a thread each time it was run, it seemed to be using the `ThreadPool`.

now what I am struggling to understand is the difference between the above and:

```
public void Main()
{
 var task = Task.Run(DoWorkASync);
}
```

From my testing, it seems that C# Thread has a different functionality when passing in an Async Expression vs the standard method on which to run>

Comment: This is very confusing because each snippet in itself is wrong. In the first, there is no await. In the second a different Thread ist started than the one created and in the third again: no awaiting the task to finish.

Comment: `Thread` constructors are not aware of `async` so the thread will start the async task and finish immediately without waiting for the asynchronous processing to finish.

Comment: [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: @GuruStron: I agree that "the thread starts the async task and finishes immediately", but I disagree with your reason "Thread constructors are not aware of async". That `async` is simply in a location that does not affect  the containing method. This `async`/`await` affects execution of the anonymous action `async () => { ... await ... }` running on the new thread. A bit like `Task.Run(async () => { ... await ... });` [returns immediately] versus `await Task.Run(async () => { ... await ... });` [suspends containing method]. Need that first `await` to affect containing method.

Comment: _"but I disagree with your reason "Thread constructors are not aware of async""_ but they are. Yes, it is a bit simplified wording. Async in this case is not just a keyword but a concept too. Of course there are edge cases of non-"truly async" methods but in most important use case - thread ctors does not have overload accepting task hence they are not aware of task-based asynchronous processing hence the original a bit simplified wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This construct:

```
var thread = new Thread(async () => { await DoWorkAync(); });
    // Start thread
proccessThread.Start();
```

Calls `Thread` constructor overload accepting `ThreadStart` delegate, and `ThreadStart` delegate is `() => void`. So you have this:

```
var thread = new Thread(StuffYourThreadExecutes);
thread.Start();   

static async void StuffYourThreadExecutes() {
    await DoWorkAsync();
}
```

So you start new thread and it runs the code until first asynchronous operation begins. Then thread exists. After that first asynchronous operation completes - the rest executes on whatever thread task scheduler providers (usually thread pool thread). Any exceptions which happen during this process cannot be observed.

For example if `DoWorkAsync` is something like:

```
static async Task DoWorkAsync(){
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Then thread starts and almost immediately exits, doing nothing useful.

`Task.Run`, when passing async delegate there, does what is stated in docs:

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a
> proxy for the task

So whole operation just runs on thread pool thread without creating threads for nothing. You can observe exceptions by awaiting task returned by `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, SO If I understand correctly, the correct way to go about this is to use the `Task.Run()` way and not the new thread way.

Comment: Yes, new thread way is first useless when used like this, and second is dangerous because you can't even observe exceptions.

Comment: @Zapnologica The correct way to do this is to simply call `DoWorkAsync` directly; no `new Thread` and no `Task.Run`. Unless you have a UI thread, and `DoWorkAsync` does enough synchronous work to impact UI responsiveness. In which case, use `Task.Run` to offload the work to the thread pool.

Comment: *"Any exceptions which happen during this process cannot be observed."*: this sentence is a bit ambiguous. One might interpret *not observed* as *fire-and-forget*, which is not the case. Exceptions thrown inside [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) methods are rethrown on the synchronization context that was captured when the `async void` method started, which results in crashing the process (in most cases).

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay *"call `DoWorkAsync` directly"* seems like the wrong "default habit" to me. I prefer starting an "async" context, `Task.Run( async ...)` or `MainThread.BeginInvoke( async ...)` etc., if it is necessary to call an `async` method from a `non-async` context. I've seen a number of SO questions with obscure symptoms, or even UI deadlocks, that could have been avoided by doing so.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Absolutely not. `Task.Run()` offloads the work to the thread pool, and the whole point of `async` is to _release threads_ whilst I/O is awaited. The general use case for `Task.Run()` is with computationally expensive work. [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html).